# Baby box vs playpen

Tags: word-choice

What's the difference?

I would suspect that it has different origins, but **playpen** can be found in both the us-/en english dictionaries. And it's a bit hard to search for **baby box** :)

Comment: Why is it a bit hard to search for [_baby box_](http://www.onelook.com/?w=baby+box&ls=a)?

Comment: Because it does not show up in US/British dictionaries because it is not an English idiom for a playpen

Comment: That's kind of what I was driving at. Not being able to find results means that it's not in use – not that it's hard to search for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most used word in English is ***playpen***

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playpen)

> A playpen is a piece of furniture in which an infant or young toddler is placed to prevent self-harm when her/his parent or guardian is occupied or away. The earliest use of the word "playpen" cited in the Oxford English Dictionary is 1902.

[image]

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/playpen)

> a portable usually collapsible enclosure in which a baby or young child may play — called also play yard

Note: The latter seems to a new word for playpen.

If you search for playpen or play yard you get the same images

- [Google images Play yard](http://goo.gl/dX7VTX)
- [Google images Playpen](http://goo.gl/RKXj14)

If you search for baby box, you will get a few playpens, from Holland or Indonesia

- [Google images Baby box](http://goo.gl/VQZiu2)

If you search amazon.com, you will find playpen and playard or Play Yard.

If you search amazon.co.uk you will find playpen only (or playards from the US).

If you search for baby box at those two sites, you will find boxes for nappies or wet napkins.

[Google nGram of playpen,play yard,baby box](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=playpen%2Cplay+yard%2Cbaby+box&year_start=1920&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cplaypen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cplay%20yard%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbaby%20box%3B%2Cc0)
[image: Playpen vs play yard vs baby box]

---

Just for completeness sake:

A [box](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_(meubelstuk)) is the Dutch word for a playpen.

If I search for box and playpen at Marktplaats:

- *Kinderen en Baby's ▶ Boxen ▶ 8.007 resultaten voor 'box'*
- *Kinderen en Baby's ▶ Boxen ▶ 23 resultaten voor 'playpen'*

Comment: _Playpen_ is the word in the U.S., too. I've not heard of "baby box" before today.

Comment: It is the word used in Holland for a playpen: _Kinderen en Baby's ▶ Boxen ▶ 8.007 resultaten voor 'box'_ vs _Kinderen en Baby's ▶ Boxen ▶ 23 resultaten voor 'playpen'_

Comment: Makes sense to me. You could put twins in there, and call it a _baby boxing ring_.

Comment: Haha. Seems popular to post youtube vids of small kids performing martial arts

Comment: @mplungjan Tnx for your explanation. Allthough I must say I don't see much value in the nr of usages on a Dutch site :)

Comment: I rather like the idea of a 'baby box'. It is just what is needed, something to put the grandchildren in and close the lid until one feels in the mood for them again!

Comment: @Jowen - it was to show non-Dutch my reasoning. I assume you are Dutch? Also if it answers your question, please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @mplungjan Indeed, I'm Dutch (you can see the location in my profile). I'm looking for a bit more formal explanation instead of usages on a website... I'll accept your answer when nobody comes up with a better one.

Comment: Please see update for formal explanation and synonym

Comment: Baby box sounds like a euphemism.